libasound2 is installed, but cannot be found
I have spotify-qt installed. Everytime I try to play a song, however, I get an error message. The log entry of spotify-qt states that it cannot find libasound2:
"/home/$username/target/release/librespot: error while loading shared libraries: libasound.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
But when I try to install libasound2 via apt-get install libasound2 Ubuntu tells me that I am already running the latest version.
What am I doing wrong? Where is libasound2? Is librespot in the wrong dir?

This question is similar to: Spotify-qt will list all songs, but will not play them. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Update your software; don't forget you're asking about a Qt package that is on an EOSS release which doesn't fall within the packages updated by ESM.
